# Why we need to nest divs?

Tags: html

What is a structure for HTML building while you're creating a index file or skeleton of the website? For instance: 1st is a Header, then Navbar etc. And why we nest the divs? isn't it better to put divs separately?

Instead of this:

```
<div id="header">  

  <div id="menubar_container">

    <div id="menubar">

      <div id="welcome">
        <h1><a href="#">Industrial Grey</a></h1>
      </div><!--close welcome-->

      <div id="menu_items">
        <ul id="menu">
          <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="ourwork.html">Our Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
          <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--close menu-->

    </div><!--close menubar-->  

  </div><!--close menubar_container-->  

</div><!--close header-->
```

Just to put all divs separately:

```
<div id="header">


</div> <!--closing the header div -->



</div id="menubar">enter code here



</div> <!-- closing the menubar div -->
```

Truth be told I watched hundreds of tutorials, read hundreds of materials, but still don't get the point of nesting the tens of divs ..

Comment: generally (IMO) to be able to apply structured CSS to parts of the page and to aid in the control of flow.

Comment: If the markup is plain as that, i don't think you need to nest it up. But in real-time scenarios we do need such nested divs. mainly for formatting and data access.

Comment: how many divs can I nest?

Comment: As many div as u want

Comment: So, div is a division, lets say a foursquare, another div is an another foresquare inside of first div and so on so forth? Or my logical approach is nor correct?

Comment: Div is a container, which makes ur job easier. Suppose u have to display 3 boxes one over each other. Then, u will first put a div, then put other 2 div in that. Then using css do it. So, nested div makes job easier.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Manish. Let me bring you an example from a template :
<div class="sidebar_container">       
  
  <div class="sidebar">
          <div class="sidebar_item">
            <h2>New Website</h2>
            <p>Welcome to our new website. Please have a look around, any feedback is much appreciated.</p>
          </div><!--close sidebar_item--> 
        </div><!--close sidebar--> 

Above, why we need there class sidebar? What it is helpful for?

Comment: @becky , class name has been given ,either it can predefined class name, which is used in many frameworks, generally we give class name to any div, so we can then give desired styling to it in css

Comment: I don't mean class name. whether given name class or id so we can style it. I meant , why to put that div? for me it seems, that there is no need for that div. since its styling goes like this. 
.sidebar
{ float: left;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;}

there is no any color etc. it is invisible, it seems to me. So why we use invisible things in there?

Comment: background--color can be given to it, then u can see it, along with width and height. Look, it's not always necessary to use a div, it always depends upon u, the way u can handle things.

Comment: Thanks. you answered all my questions. Now I got this. cool :)

Comment: You look an wonderful enthusiast, keep going @becky

Comment: Thanks a lot Manish,I'll

Answer (score 0):

Nesting DIVs can make styling the website easier.
Let's say that you want to add a margin to a specific part of your site (like in an article with multiple sections, but not the header or footer). By putting your article's main content in nested DIVs, the margin will be applied to the whole section easily.

(You won't need multiple pieces of CSS to achieve the effect.)

Also, nest DIVs helps you organise the DOM. This may make it easier for you to find a specific part of your code in the Developer tools. Your website will also be more accessible.

TLDR: Nesting DIVs are best practice.